# How to make animations run smoothly on long pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, render

With Javascript and a PHP back end I created a small website for personal use. It fetches all images from a specific tumblr. The Idea behind it is that I can quickly click on images I like to save them to my desktop.

WHen the site has fetched everything I have a page-height of at least 120,000px and a huge dom. I noticed that the transitions that worked fine with just 4 images on the page do not work smoothly anymore. They stutter.

How can I fix this? (i thought It has something to do with the page rendering)

Im on Windows 8 using the newest version of Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to have a lazy load (e.g. scroll to load) if you have a page that tall, as that's consuming a huge amount of memory.